# Win32 API: CreateFont/SelectObject not rendering text properly on a different computer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, fonts

I cloned and tweaked a version of [Open-Shell](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu) on Visual Studio and used their makefile to compile it into an installer. To be more specific, I wanted to make the 'All Programs' text button bold:

[image]

To do so, I called [CreateFont](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) inside `Src/StartMenu/StartMenuDLL/MenuPaint.cpp` on line 2336 (which gets called each time you open the start menu):

```
CString name = s_MenuMode == MODE_PROGRAMS ? FindTranslation(L"Menu.Back", L"Back") : FindTranslation(L"Menu.AllPrograms", L"All Programs"); // String is 'All Programs' or 'Back', both of which I want bold

HFONT hFont = CreateFont(32, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, L"Segoe UI");

SelectObject(hdc, hFont); // Selects the font into the device context for drawing the text
```

Further down in the code, there is a call to [DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) to display the text.

After compiling the project into the installer, I installed the program on both the desktop I made the changes on and a clean virtual machine and it works:

[image]

However, when I run the installer on my laptop, the changes to the text are not applied.

I tested both `CreateFont` and `SelectObject` and neither of these return any error on any of the machines. The virtual machine and the laptop are both running Windows 21H1 so I don't think this is a Windows version issue.

I am a bit clueless about what could be causing this otherwise. I never played with the Windows API before. Is there a library I am missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that you should not call SelectObject while handling WM_CREATE, perform that action in your WM_PAINT handler. WM_CREATE doesn't even have a DC available (unless you call GetDC or the like).

Comment: Your code doesn't check for errors. [CreateFont](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfontw) can fail.

Comment: @IInspectable Indeed I removed the error-checking code after noticing these functions do not fail.

Comment: `CreateFont` depends on per-system state. You cannot test on one system, observe the outcome, and then conclude that the outcome were the same on every other system.

Comment: @IInspectable This is not what I did. I compiled it with the error checking code and ran it through all systems and none of them failed. I got it of the code afterwards. I did mention that in my post but maybe it was not clear.

Comment: If I followed your references correctly, the `CMenuContainer::DrawBackground` function starts at https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu/blob/master/Src/StartMenu/StartMenuDLL/MenuPaint.cpp#L1543 and goes for almost 1,000 lines. How sure are you that you managed the font lifetime correctly? Did you really create a new font for each `OnPaint`? What exactly did you log to make sure your code was running on the system in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the code does work on my laptop. However, another program is interfering/overriding font settings (WindowBlinds 10 in this case).

My approach is still not ideal (as stated by [Vlad Feinstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4394169/vlad-feinstein)) but I hope it helps.